# Testing ember controllers that use mixins with DOM logic

Tags: ember.js

How can I change this mixin, that I call in a controller, so that I am able to run tests.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default
Ember.Mixin.create({
  scrollViewTo: function (navigateToId) {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce("afterRender", function () {
      Ember.$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: Ember.$(navigateToId).offset().top}, 1000);
    });
  }
});
```

Any code in my test that results in `scrollViewTo` beign called result in this:

```
 at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:14:29: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I suspect I need to move all this logic to events in my view?

Comment: I don’t have experience with this, but I don’t think there’s anything conceptually wrong with a mixin intended for views (other than that views are going away in Ember 2.0). When testing your mixin, maybe you just need to mix it in to a rendered view for testing.

Comment: Have you tried console logging `navigateToId` or putting a break point inside the scheduleOnce? It looks like that variable just isn't what you think it is.